# Hypothetical size of divs in flexbox vs "real" size in flow layout mode?

Tags: css, flexbox

Consider the following example:

```html
    <div class="item"></div>
    
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
```

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

The first `div` in flow layout mode will have predefined size, i.e. `width: 2000px;`, but the second one in flexbox layout mode will be smaller. Why is that? AFAIK, its container is the limiting factor, but I don't see how it is true in this case, since I did not limit size of `.flex-wrapper`.

Comment: _"since I did not limit size of .flex-wrapper"_ - it has an inherent default width of 100%,;that is the same for `flex` as it would be for a basic `display:block` element. And the item inside it is allowed to shrink, because the default value for [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) is `1`.

Comment: Thanks. That is the solution. I don't know how to mark is a solution?